# Django webfaction deployment: How to change the default directory of your project

Tags: django, deployment, web-deployment, webfaction

im deploying my django project, named "Hesperides" under a webfaction server. The default project's folder in webfaction it's "myproject" so Im having this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings
```

**The question is:** How can i do to import the settings from Hesperides.settings instead from myproject.settings? Thanks for your time.

**My httpd.conf:**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess jinn processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/zeioth/webapps/jinn:/home/zeioth/webapps/jinn/myproject:/home/zeioth/webapps/jinn/lib/python2.7:
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zeioth/webapps/jinn/myproject/Hesperides/wsgi.py
```

**My wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Hesperides.settings'
application = WSGIHandler()
```

**My folder tree:**

```
jinn
  --apache2
    -bin
    --conf
      -httpd.conf
      -mime.types
    -lib
    -logs
    -modules
  -bin
  -lib
  --myproject
    -manage.py
    --Hesperides
      -wsgi.py
      -urls.py
      -__init__.py
      -settings.py
      -apps
```

Comment: Seems to me your `settings.py` is actually inside `myproject`. Have you tried to copy/paste `settings.py` inside `Hesperides` folder?

Comment: no, this is myproject folder:
http://oi39.tinypic.com/mjsscw.jpg

Comment: I don't understand quite well your file tree structure.Try this instead `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Hesperides.settings")`

Comment: Im having the same problem. i don't know there could be the problem.
http://oi42.tinypic.com/d9pqf.jpg

Comment: Can you post the exception full traceback? Try to search within your project for myproject.settings. Maybe it's not wsgi.py

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED: These are the steps to change your project directory under webfaction:

1-in httpd.conf in webapps/yourappname/apache2 set:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/zeioth/webapps/jinn/myproject/yourNewName/wsgi.py
```

2-in your app's manage.py set:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourNewName.settings")
```

3-in your app's wsgi.py set:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'yourNewName.settings'
```

4-In your app's settings.py set:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION ='yourNewName.wsgi.application'
```

Now, runserver should work, or tell you if you need to install some module.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you have use WSGIDaemonProcess you need to have a corresponding WSGIProcessGroup directive else your WSGI application will not be delegated to run in that daemon process group. WebFaction was generating a broken configuration file for a while if I remember. That or you copied this from one of the blog posts out there which have broken examples. Read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode